# Помогите написать условие для вывода ссылки на изображение

Tags: php, wordpress, img, thumbnails

Моя тема wordpress генерирует некоторые копии изображения различного разрешения:

```
add_image_size( 'background-3000', '3000', '2000', true ); // 1
add_image_size( 'background-2000', '2000', '1000', true ); // 2
add_image_size( 'background-1000', '1000', '500', true ); // 3
```

Затем я пытаюсь выводить ссылки на скачивание этих копий на странице:

```
<?php $intermediate = image_get_intermediate_size( $imageid, 'background-3000'); // Кнопка__1
echo '<a href="'.$intermediate[url] .'" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" download="" title="Кликни, чтобы скачать изображение">
<button class="button btn-dwl"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.$intermediate[width]."×".$intermediate[height].' px</button></a>'?>
                
<?php $intermediate = image_get_intermediate_size( $imageid, 'background-2000'); // Кнопка__2
 echo '<a href="'.$intermediate[url] .'" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" download="" title="Кликни, чтобы скачать изображение">
<button class="button btn-dwl"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.$intermediate[width]."×".$intermediate[height].' px</button></a>'?>
                
<?php $intermediate = image_get_intermediate_size( $imageid, 'background-1000'); // Кнопка__3
 echo '<a href="'.$intermediate[url] .'" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" download="" title="Кликни, чтобы скачать изображение">
<button class="button btn-dwl"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.$intermediate[width]."×".$intermediate[height].' px</button></a>'?>
```

Если загрузить изображение например 2500px, то кнопка "Кнопка__1" выводится с пустым значением, т.к. изображения с таким разрешением не существует. Помогите написать условие, что бы кнопка не выводилась вообще, если данного разрешения не существует.

[image: вот так выводятся кнопки :(]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так проверь ифом, возвращает чего-либо твоя функция, или нет. Если пусто, не выводи. Можно и без if, по модному написать:

```
<?php echo image_get_intermediate_size( $imageid, 'background-3000') == "" ? '' : '<a href="'.$intermediate[url] .'" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" download="" title="Кликни, чтобы скачать изображение">
<button class="button btn-dwl"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>'.$intermediate[width]."×".$intermediate[height].' px</button></a>'; ?>
```